# Is it possible to show the structure of the repository using DESC files?

Tags: git, gitignore

Part of the repository structure:

```
|-- data
|---- first_folder
|---- second_folder
|---- ...
|---- last_folder
|---- DESC
|-- .gitignore
```

In the folder `data` and in each inner folder there are several files, that should be ignored by git, and `DESC` file, that I want see in my repository.

If I use the following `.gitignore`, then `DESC` files in all inner folders are ignored.

```
data/*
!DESC
```

I can write something like that to see inner `DESC` files:

```
data/*/*
!DESC
```

But firstly, I can only do this because of the simple file structure. And secondly, in this case, all files situated in the folder `data` are not ignored.